# Android NDK - Does my app leaking memory when it allocated the memory and then crash happened?

Tags: c++, android-ndk

I have the following code like this. In normal flow, the `foo()` method will allocate some memory, process it, and then release it. But let say something unexpected happened and let it to crashes. So my question is: Does the `ptr` will free the memory for me when the crash happened?

```
#include<memory>

void my_app_package_name_some_class_some_method_name(jclass clazz)
{
  foo();
}

void foo()
{
   std::unique_ptr<int> ptr(new int[1000]);
   
   // Let say something happened and then it crashes here, for example, I just call abort()
  abort();

  // working with the ptr here ...
  
  // done working with ptr
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It will not. From cppreference on `std::abort`:

> Destructors of variables with **automatic**, thread local (since C++11) and static storage durations are not called.